# What do Catholics think of the Philokalia?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, mysticism

The absence of a "mysticism"-oriented text in Catholic Christianity has always struck me. The *Philokalia* are an incredible source of ascetic instructions for the believer who seeks communion with God.

(1) In what consideration do Catholic Christians keep the Philokalia?
And, (2) is there a similar text in the Catholic tradition?

Answer (score 2):

The Catholic Church has no problem with the *Philokalia*; it is a legitimate mystical text in the Eastern Christian tradition. [Eastern Catholics make use of it all the time](http://easterncatholicspiritualrenewal.blogspot.it/2014/02/rediscovering-philokalia.html). (I am not aware of any official pronouncement by the Magisterium, but all of the authors are well regarded monks.)

As far as mysticism in the Western Church, there is not a “single” work, but there is long tradition of mysticism. For example, among many others works, there is the following:

- [*El castillo interior* (*The Interior Castle*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Interior_Castle) of [St. Theresa of Avila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teresa_of_%C3%81vila).
- The works of [St. John of the Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_the_Cross).
- The works of [St. Hildegard of Bingen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_of_Bingen).
- The works of [St. Bernard of Clairvaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Clairvaux).
- Many works inspired by the writings of [(Pseudo)-Dionysius the Areopagite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Dionysius_the_Areopagite), including the anonymous [*Cloud of Unknowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cloud_of_Unknowing).

Comment: Don't forget *The Cloud of Unknowing*.